# Laravel объединить результат из 2х таблиц в одну

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel5, eloquent

Стоит задача, вывести результат из 2х таблиц в одну коллекцию.

Как я понял, нужно объединить 2 таблицы, это я сделал вот так:

```
$travel = Travel::query();
$home = Home::query();

$travel = $travel->get();
$query = $query->get();


$all = $travel->merge($home);
```

Такой вариант работает без проблем, таблицы объединяются, но вот пагинация теперь не работает, тоесть когда я передаю это в представление:

```
return view('table')->with('all', $all);
```

Я не могу в представлении вызвать пагинацию `$all->links()`

Смотрел различные решения с помощью класса `Paginator`, но так и не получилось вызвать пагинацию в представлении.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420505/how-can-i-paginate-a-merged-collection-in-laravel-5

Comment: да, я уже видел эту ссылку, но так и не понял как он в представлении вызывает пагинацию ?

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод union
[Laravel union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#unions)

```
$travel = DB::table('travel');

$home = DB::table('home')
            ->union($travel )
            ->get();
```

Но union из коробки не правильно работает с пагинацией, поэтому для пагинации используй следующий трюк (пример замени своим):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input;
use Request;
use View;
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $page = Input::get('page', 1);
        $paginate = 10;

        $travel = DB::table("travel");
        $data = DB::table("home")
                    ->union($travel)
                    ->get();

        $offSet = ($page * $paginate) - $paginate;
        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($data, $offSet, $paginate, true);
        $data = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($data), $paginate, $page);

        return View::make('index',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовал класс отсюда https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

но проблема была в том, что пагинация обнулала query string в запросе, поэтому поменял строчку в классе, чтобы параметры запроса тоже учитывались

```
LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath()
```

поменял на

```
LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath() . "?" . \Request::getQueryString();
```